# How can I locate and debug a specific file in IE11 Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I have a file that is part of a legacy web site I'm maintaining that I need to debug - step into, etc. But I can't see how to do that. The site needs to be run in IE, in Compatibility mode.

When I run the site from VS (2013) by right-clicking the "http://localhost/..." item beneath the solution and selecting "View in Browser (Internet Explorer" and then hit F12, I see on the Debugger tab the file that has been set as the Default page (the "main" page I see after logging in), but from there I don't see how to open a different file - the one I need to debug.

There are a handful of files apparently available for selection beneath the folder icon:

[image]

...but not the one I need. If I enter its name in the search box, I get, "No results found." It is beneath a pages folder, but so are those that are displayed. What makes them special? Why can I select those undesirables, but cannot select the only page I care about?

Comment: What is the extension of the file you are trying to view?

Comment: .aspx; it's an ancient ASP.NET (2.0) app/site.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you load that page in the browser?  I don't think it will show unless that ASPX page has been loaded.

Comment: Yes, it is the "live" page when I try to find the source file.

Comment: Are you trying to debug back-end code of your aspx file? Or some embedded JavaScript code?

Comment: @Ignas: javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have the JavaScript file you want to debug somewhere in dist. Just go to that file and write `debugger;` inside the function you want to debug. The open dev tools in IE and reload the page. Initiate an action that should invoke that function with debugger (if it was not done on page load) and you will be able to debug it.

Comment: Interesting; I'll give that a try.

Comment: However, it's not a javascript file; everything is contained in one file (VB, html, and javascript); what I need to find and open is the .aspx file, which has javascript in it.

Comment: Yes, exactly, find the JavaScript function no matter where it is located.